# CHKDSK stuck at 30% for hours - can't boot to Windows

Tags: windows-8, boot, partitioning, chkdsk

I have a laptop with a Windows 8 partition (412.00 GB) and a recently-created Ubuntu 18.04 LTS partition (36.51 GB). My goal is to shrink the Windows partition (I have some free space there) to make more room on the Ubuntu side.

Following [a tutorial](https://www.aomeitech.com/windows-8/shrink-volume-windows-8-1234.html) to shrink the Windows partition from within Windows, I ran into some trouble at the `shrink querymax` step, and was informed that I needed to use `chkdsk` because the partition was apparently corrupted.

I've since tried to boot Windows three separate times, but the `chkdsk` 'repairs' never make it beyond 30% (I left it on for two straight hours once to be sure).

I can still boot into Ubuntu and can still access all my Windows files from there, but am unable to boot into Windows.

How do I resolve this? Is there any way at all while booting to skip the `chkdsk` repairs?

EDIT: To be clear, I *was* still able to boot into Windows and have everything function normally after I created the Ubuntu partition, and the Windows partition still had 30+ GB of free space left. The problem did not start until after I decided to run `chkdsk`.

Answer (score 0):

You have apparent shrunk Windows to a size that's too small and broke it.

You will need to restore Windows to to a workable size.
I recommend using for that a Windows utility, rather than a Linux utility
that might break it still more.

As your Windows partition is broken, you will need to create a boot
Windows PE (WinPE) USB disk.

You may find links to some such ready-made in the article
[5 Bootable Windows PE ISO To Boot, Recover And Repair Windows](https://www.geckoandfly.com/32030/bootable-windows-pe-recovery-repair/).

It contains links to MediCat USB, Sergei Strelec’s WinPE, Hiren’s BootCD PE
and others.
If you cannot create the boot USB on your computer, ask some friend for help.

Once you boot into WinPE, use Disk Management to resize the partition.
Ensure that it has lots of free space.

Comment: I'm not sure this applies. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I don't think that I've actually broken Windows. I've added some clarification to my question.

Comment: If currently you cannot boot then this answer might apply. Do you know how much free disk space you had when you booted into Windows?

Comment: The Windows partition had (and still has, I can see this from within Ubuntu) 37.6 GB available.

Comment: That's more than enough. Can you check the SMART data of the disk?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know what that is. I've tried googling, but 'SMART data' seems to give a lot of false positives because of the common meaning of 'smart'.

Comment: This might help. Add the data to the post if you need help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1